# Is there a way to get python to find a file name based on a changing date variable?

Tags: python, string, csv, date

I'm trying to define a function that pulls data out of a newly exported csv every day, where the name of the csv changes based on the day.

So far I have the following:

```
import pandas as pd

todays_date = pd.to_datetime('today').strftime('%Y%m%d')

todays_date_name_string = 'unchanging part of filename ' + str(todays_date)

var1 = fnmatch.filter(os.listdir('P:directory/'), 'todays_date_name_string*.csv')

print(var1)
```

But an empty list is printed. I can't seem to get it to take the variable even though when I print  todays_date_name_string by itself I get the string I want, am I using fnmatch or os.listdir incorrectly?

Comment: The code you shared is not a valid code - it can not run. Start by sharing a **valid** code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```py
var1 = fnmatch.filter(os.listdir('P:directory/'), 'todays_date_name_string*.csv')
```

to

```py
var1 = fnmatch.filter(os.listdir('P:directory/'), f'{todays_date_name_string}*.csv')
```

Your problem is that you're trying to use the variable `todays_date_name_string`, which contains todays date as a string, but you're not actually using it. You're using the *string* `todays_date_name_string`, so you're basically just trying to get all files that start with, literally `todays_date_name_string`, and end with `.csv`.